# How to select property based on value?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following object,

```
const {
  dev,
  qa,
  staging,
  prod,
  customEnv,
} = argv;
```

Where values are undefined or boolean.

I want to select the environment by doing something like this;

```
const env =
  customEnvironment ||
  dev ||
  qa ||
  staging ||
  prod;
```

1. But I want to get environment name instead of value. How can I do that (shorthand)?

(if prod is true env should be 'prod')

2. How can I do that without hardcoding environment names like above?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use all the variable's as key value pair in object and than find the first true value and access it's key

```js
let customEnvironment = false, dev = true, qa = false, staging = false, prod = false

let tempObj = {customEnvironment,
  dev,
  qa,
  staging,
  prod}


let op = Object.entries(tempObj).find(([,value])=>value)[0]

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the first property that is set following a specific *order*, then you should really use an array of those property names, like this:

```js
const argv = { staging: "2.1", prod: "2.1" };

const env = ["customEnvironment", "dev", "qa", "staging", "prod"].find(key => argv[key]);

console.log(env);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop:

```
let env;
const props = ["customEnvironment", "dev", "qa", "staging", "prod"];
for (let i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    if (argv[props[i]]) {
        env = props[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

I can't think of a good way to do it without hard-coding the array of properties, because you need to specify the priority order somewhere.